# Subscrever um objeto em JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de subscrever o conteúdo de um objeto. Por exemplo:
Tenho dois objetos.

```
object1 {
 name: '';
 address = 'Rua Mario';
 email: '';
}
```

```
object 2 {
 name: 'Carlos';
 email: 'Carlos@email.com';
}
```

A dúvida ocorre aqui.

```
this.object1 = this.object2;
console.log(this.object1);
```

Resultado no console:

```
object 1 {
 name: 'Carlos';
 email: 'Carlos@email.com';
}
```

O que eu queria:

```
object 1 {
 name: 'Carlos';
 address = 'Rua Mario';
 email: 'Carlos@email.com';
}
```

Qual o meio mais fácil de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let object1 = {
   name: '',
   address: 'Rua Mario',
   email: '',
}

let object2 = {
    name: 'Carlos',
    email: 'Carlos@email.com'
}

const {name, email} = object2;
object1 = {...object1, name, email};

console.log(object1);
```

Comment: Sua resposta é boa, tanto é que dei +1, mas, poderia explicar como fez para chegar ao resultado e não apenas publicar a resposta, assim fica mais didático para quem perguntou e para futuras pesquisas!